How can I restore all Programs from a corrupt Windows 10 System to a new Install of Win 10
I have a corrupt Windows 10 (in Windows.old) and could install a new entity of Windows 10 in Windows on C:.
Can I restore all Programs from my windows.old by transferring the Registry hive under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE : \system32\config\software by moving the the files in  \system32\config\software from my old Windows to my new Windows folder and moving the Program Directories also from my old to new windows?
My old Windows 10 cannot be repaired by the Windows REPAIR process anymore so I can not start it again. Is there a way to save the programs installed on the old system?
Thanks

No. Moving Registry data from one instance of Windows to another is almost certain to cause errors in the OS, making the PC unbootable, and likely requiring Windows reinstallation de novo. If you had a drive image of the machine in its previous working state, that whole image can be safely restored, and the PC would be as it was at the moment the image was made.

Windows.old will be mostly deleted 28 days after the new Windows was
installed, so I suggest to at least rename it, if you wish to keep it.
What you suggest is not possible, although many people have looked for it.
You will need to install in the new Windows all your applications from scratch
and do their settings.
You may use Windows.old to give an idea of what you need to install.
You may try to copy some settings files of some applications to their new
installation folders, but you can't do that for Windows.
You may also consult the old registry hives.
See the article
Use Regedit for Offline Registry Hive Editing.
Be careful, since installing the new Windows might have kept the old
installation folders of the applications that were installed before
the problem happened. You might get a mix-up of old and new data.
I also suggest to do chkdsk to verify the state of the disk,
and to consult its SMART data to ensure that the crash didn't happen
because of the disk degrading.
